# Linq GroupBy Display Details from List

Tags: c#, linq, umbraco7

[image]

**UPDATE** I have added an image to show what is returned
I'm trying to create a menu where the category and manufacturer is displayed (which I can get data from) but I'm unable to get the product from the list which is in the GroupBy.

My code is:

```
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> getAllProducts = UmbracoAssignedContentHelper.PageContentByAlias("productCatalog").Children;

var result = getAllProducts.GroupBy(x => new { Manufacturer = x.GetPropertyValue<string>("manufacturer"), Category = x.GetPropertyValue<string>("category")})
    .Select(b => new ProductsGroupByTypeViewModel
    {
        GetAllProductsGroupByType   = b.Select(bn => bn.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<string>>("product").ToList()),
        Category                    = b.Key.Category,
        Manufacturer                = b.Key.Manufacturer

    }).ToList();

var listOfProducts = result.ToList();
```

VIEW MODEL

```
public IEnumerable<List<string>> GetAllProductsGroupByType { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
```

My Last attempt was

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var data in Model)
    {
        <li>@data.GetAllProductsGroupByType</li> <---------What do I need to do here
    }
</ul>
```

which displays

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]

How can I drill down and get the product data to display?

Any help would be appreciated

As for Eldho answer, I have tried that and it does not work. I get the error.

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   From `GetAllProductsGroupByType   = b.Select(bn => bn.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<string>>("product").ToList()),`

Comment: You need to iterate the GetAllProductsGroupByType to get single values.

`@foreach (var data in Model)
    {
        <li>foreach(var item in data.GetAllProductsGroupByType</li> 
    }`
Something like this

Comment: Hi @Eldho, that does not work as I have tried it

Comment: Hi @Kiran Joshi, that does not work

Comment: @foreach (var data in Model) { <li>foreach(var item in data.GetAllProductsGroupByType[0]</li> } try this

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it by single group by and select. Maybe the below snippet work

```
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> getAllProducts = UmbracoAssignedContentHelper.PageContentByAlias("productCatalog").Children;

var result = getAllProducts.GroupBy(x => new { Manufacturer = x.GetPropertyValue<string>("manufacturer"), Category = x.GetPropertyValue<string>("category")})
    .Select(b => new ProductsGroupByTypeViewModel
    {
        GetAllProductsGroupByType   = new List<string>(),
        Category                    = b.Key.Category,
        Manufacturer                = b.Key.Manufacturer

    }).ToList();

froeach(var item in result)
{
    item.GetAllProductsGroupByType = getAllProducts.Where(en => en.manufacturer == item.Manufacturer && en.category == item.Category).Select(en => en.product).ToList();
}

//now you can use result as your answer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> getAllProducts = UmbracoAssignedContentHelper.PageContentByAlias("productCatalog").Children;

var result = getAllProducts.GroupBy(x => new { Manufacturer = x.GetPropertyValue<string>("manufacturer"), Category = x.GetPropertyValue<string>("category")})
    .Select(b => new ProductsGroupByTypeViewModel
    {
        GetAllProductsGroupByType   = b.Select(bn => bn.GetPropertyValue<List<string>>("product")),
        Category                    = b.Key.Category,
        Manufacturer                = b.Key.Manufacturer

    }).ToList();

var listOfProducts = result.ToList();
```

Data Model

```
public List<List<string>> GetAllProductsGroupByType { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
```

View

```
@foreach (var data in Model)
{
    if(data.GetAllProductsGroupByType != null || data.GetAllProductsGroupByType.Count == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    foreach(var item in data.GetAllProductsGroupByType)
    {
       <li>item</li>
    }
}
```